# Как сделать вывод новости на отдельную странцу по ID в PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку "Читать далее" конкретная новость появлялась на отдельной странице?

```
<?
    // Текущая страница
    if (isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }else $page = 1;

    $kol = 10;  //количество записей для вывода
    $art = ($page * $kol) - $kol;

    // Определяем все количество записей в таблице
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `data`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $total = $row[0]; // всего записей  


    // Количество страниц для пагинации
    $str_pag = ceil($total / $kol);


    // Запрос и вывод записей
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $art,$kol");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{

    echo "  <div class='col-lg-4 mb-4'>
            <div class='entry2'>
              <a href='single.html'><img src=".$myrow["description"]." alt='Image' class='img-fluid rounded'></a>
              <div class='excerpt'>
              <span class='post-category text-white bg-secondary mb-3'>Politics</span>

              <h2><a href='single.html'> ".$myrow["title"]." </a></h2>
              <div class='post-meta align-items-center text-left clearfix'>
                <figure class='author-figure mb-0 mr-3 float-left'><img src='images/img_3.jpg' alt='Image' class='img-fluid'></figure>
                <span class='d-inline-block mt-1'>By <a href='#'>".$myrow["author"]."</a></span>
                <span>&nbsp;-&nbsp; ".$myrow["date"]."</span>
              </div>

                <p>".$myrow["text"]."</p>
                <p><a href='single.php?index=".$myrow["id"]."'>Читать далее</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> ";



} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
        // формируем пагинацию
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $str_pag; $i++){
        echo "
        <div class='row text-center pt-5 border-top'>
          <div class='col-md-12'>
            <div class='custom-pagination'>
             <a class='page' href=index.php?page=".$i." > ".$i." </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Нужно что бы открывалась в отдельной вкладке?

Comment: <p><a href='single.php?index=".$myrow["id"]." target="_blank"'>Читать далее</a></p>


target="_blank" - откроет в новой странице. А там по id получить данные